# How can I assign an action to an armature using Animation Nodes

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

Animation nodes took a while to get the hang of it, but it is truly amazing. 
I've been following the example below, but rather than modify an existing action, I'd like to assign a random action to each of the duplicated armatures. The scene currently has 5 actions (ArmatureAction.000, ArmatureAction.001, ArmatureAction.002 etc.)

I just can't work out how to firstly assign an action to an object using AN, and secondly how to randomly assign one of the 5 actions to each of the armature duplicates.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q9unQC3PTcI&feature=youtu.be

[image: Animation-Nodes-Armature-action]

[image: Animation Nodes Actions]

[File on Dropbox - 800K](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oruvbodj70pogjc/Animation%20Nodes%20Armature.blend?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it. But the main problem with your node setup is  that your using the second Object Attribute Output in wrong way. You haven´t passed any value to node. Therefore no paremeter can be assigned.

Comment: OK, can you tell me how to do it please? Here is the NodeTree that instances the object, and the armatures and connects them together. But I can't work out the syntax to place a different Action on the NLA track in each of the instances.

Comment: Do you mean that I have to put in a New Parameter in the Loop Input node?

Comment: Can you share the file and I´ll try to post an arrangement tomorrow?

Comment: Excellent, thank you, this has been driving me nuts. :)There's a link now under the image.

Comment: @Denaro If this answer is helpful, please consider to vote and select as your answer. :)